# XSLT - merge sub nodes into one

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file original="TargetInteresting1/Localizable.strings" >
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.">
                <source>Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.</source>
                <target>City must contain at least 2 letters. Characters like ' and - are allowed.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%ix einlösebereit!">
                <source>%ix einlösebereit!</source>
                <target>%ix ready to redeem</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
    <file original="TargetInteresting2/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.">
                <source>Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.</source>
                <target>City must contain at least 2 letters. Characters like ' and - are allowed.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
    <file original="TargetInteresting3/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="%@ - %@">
                <source>%1$@ - %2$@</source>
                <target>%1$@ - %2$@</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%ix einlösebereit!">
                <source>%ix einlösebereit!</source>
                <target>%ix ready to redeem</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
    <file original="TargetNotInteresting1/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="%@ - %@">
                <source>%1$@ - %2$@</source>
                <target>%1$@ - %2$@</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

and I need this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file original="TargetMerged/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.">
                <source>Die Stadt muss mindestens 2 Buchstaben aufweisen. Die Zeichen ' und - sind erlaubt.</source>
                <target>City must contain at least 2 letters. Characters like ' and - are allowed.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%ix einlösebereit!">
                <source>%ix einlösebereit!</source>
                <target>%ix ready to redeem</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%@ - %@">
                <source>%1$@ - %2$@</source>
                <target>%1$@ - %2$@</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
    <file original="TargetNotInteresting1/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="%@ - %@">
                <source>%1$@ - %2$@</source>
                <target>%1$@ - %2$@</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%ix einlösebereit!">
                <source>%ix einlösebereit!</source>
                <target>%ix ready to redeem</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
    <file original="TargetNotInteresting2/Localizable.strings">
        <header>
            <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="%@ - %@">
                <source>%1$@ - %2$@</source>
                <target>%1$@ - %2$@</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.">
                <source>Die Standorte konnten nicht geladen werden.</source>
                <target>Could not load locations.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="%ix einlösebereit!">
                <source>%ix einlösebereit!</source>
                <target>%ix ready to redeem</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="Die Straße muss angegeben werden.">
                <source>Die Straße muss angegeben werden.</source>
                <target>Street is a mandatory field.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

It needs to do the following:

create a new `<file>` node: 
`<file original="TargetMerged/Localizable.strings"...>`
and move all `<trans-unit>` nodes from `<file original = "TargetInteresting1/Localizable.strings"`, `<file original = "TargetInteresting2/Localizable.strings"` and `<file original = "TargetInteresting3/Localizable.strings"`
into that merged node (if it's not already there, I guess this can be checked using the `id` attribute of `<trans-unit>`).

Nodes, that do NOT have any of the 3 `original` attribute values (TargetInteresting1, TargetInteresting2, TargetInteresting3) should be copied into the final result unmodified.

I am looking for a solution with xslt 2.0. I don't know where to start, I'm not really used to xslt :-(

Comment: Could you reduce the examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem? See: [mcve]. Also please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at the code.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to reduce my examples for better understanding, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following **minimized** example:

**XML**

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file original="TargetInteresting1/Localizable.strings">
        <trans-unit>1</trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>2</trans-unit>
    </file> 
    <file original="TargetInteresting2/Localizable.strings">
        <trans-unit>3</trans-unit>
    </file> 
    <file original="TargetInteresting3/Localizable.strings">
        <trans-unit>4</trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>5</trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>6</trans-unit>
    </file> 
    <file original="TargetNotInteresting1/Localizable.strings">
        <trans-unit>7</trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>8</trans-unit>
    </file> 
    <file original="TargetNotInteresting2/Localizable.strings">
        <trans-unit>9</trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>10</trans-unit>
    </file> 
</xliff>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/xliff">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="regex">TargetInteresting[1-3]/Localizable.strings</xsl:variable>
        <file original="TargetMerged/Localizable.strings">
            <xsl:copy-of select="file[matches(@original,$regex)]/trans-unit"/>
        </file>
        <xsl:copy-of select="file[not(matches(@original,$regex))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
   <file original="TargetMerged/Localizable.strings">
      <trans-unit>1</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>2</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>3</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>4</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>5</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>6</trans-unit>
   </file>
   <file original="TargetNotInteresting1/Localizable.strings">
      <trans-unit>7</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>8</trans-unit>
   </file>
   <file original="TargetNotInteresting2/Localizable.strings">
      <trans-unit>9</trans-unit>
      <trans-unit>10</trans-unit>
   </file>
</xliff>
```

http://xsltransform.net/a9Giws

Comment: Thanks! How would I avoid having duplicates? I have updated the code here: http://xsltransform.net/a9Giws/1

Comment: @gasparuff - you can try grouping them: http://xsltransform.net/a9Giws/2

Comment: What Daniel said - except I guess you want to use `group-by=@id` in your actual implementation.